# Calling a method, C#

Tags: c#, methods

I can't get it to work! When I type this code in main to call the method "CreateJuice":

```
var totalSum = OrangeJuice.CreateJuice(AddOranges());
```

I get this error: The name AddOranges does not exist in the current context. I need help calling my method.

How can I call my CreateJuice method?

Comment: Where do you define `CreateJuice` and `AddOrange`? You don't show the class name. You showed things that don't matter and hidden things that matter.

Comment: Since AddOranges is a staic method you need to preface it with the name of the class.  So if the class is Fruit, then calling Fruit.AddOranges() would return your list.

Comment: "AddOranges does not exist in the current context" -- Maybe if you called it by its actual name, `AddOrange()`? That is, assuming that's not a typo from typing up the question. If it is, then look at the `classname.method()` suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

you need to qualify the method call with the class name since it's static

```
var totalSum = OrangeJuice.CreateJuice(OrangeJuice.AddOranges());
```

I'm assuming they are in the same class.